# Bootstrap 2 or Bootstrap 3 how to collapse open accordion

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am building own accordion markup by using bootstrap collapse

Does anyone know how to close the open accordion when you click on any other?

I tried with

```
        //bs2
        $('#top1_accordion').on('show','.collapse', function() {
            $('#top1_accordion').find('.collapse.in').collapse('hide');
        }); 
        //bs3
        $('#top1_accordion').on('show.bs.collapse','.collapse', function() {
            $('#top1_accordion').find('.collapse.in').collapse('hide');
        });
```

bootstrap 3 works on first click only
http://jsfiddle.net/4WsFK/1/

I got it working on bootstrap 2

http://jsfiddle.net/MTKp7/26/

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: [Bootstrap 3 Collapse](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the this fiddle should work.  I only removed the class 'collapse' from your find statement.  I'm not sure of all differences in 3.0, but they must've changed the markup slightly.

```
$('#top1_accordion').find('in').collapse('hide');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9jZDE/1/

Comment: Thank you!, should have tried with in class only. That is only one left from prev version. Thnx much.